# Facing error related to node-gyp while installing jsthemis

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am unable to install an npm package `jsthemis` on my NodeJS project. I am using `node version: 11.15.0` & `npm version: 6.7.0` on my system.

While installing the aforementioned package, I am getting the following error:

[image]

I cannot upgrade my node version, as doing so will break other things in my project. I have tried installing `node-gyp` globally too but it did not help me as well. Tried installing `jsthemis` package after deleting `node modules` and `package-lock.json` too but the error persisted.

**P.S.** I have researched sufficiently before posting this question but none of the solutions helped me.